# Left quasi-inverse elements: motivation

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

An element $a$ in a ring $R$ is a left quasi-inverse if there exists $b\in R$ such that $a+b=ba.$ What is the motivation behind this definition?

Answer (score 4):

Consider an equation like $(1-b)(1-a)=1$, which says that $1-a$ has a left inverse $1-b$.  Multiplying through, and cancelling the $1$'s, we are left with $a+b=ba$.  This expresses essentially the same identity, but without needing to reference $1$.  So, it works perfectly well in nonunital rings, and can thus generalize invertibility to nonunital rings.